# prevent previous insert when failed to insert

Tags: c#, mysql

I have multiple functions to save (insert) to database.

What I want is, if there is 1 function which gets an error saving (inserting) to the database,  any previous saves (inserts) are not committed.

For example:

```
//button click event
 Try
    insert_a()
    insert_b() 
    insert_c()
    insert_d()
 Catch
    MsgBox("Failed to insertaaaaa !")
 End Try
//
```

Let's say the error I got was in `insert_c`, but `insert_a` and `insert_b` already ran and saved (inserted) to the database.

How do I not commit the `save` to database for `c` and `a` and also stop running `insert_d` function?

Comment: inserting a bulk of records or just one record per insert function?

Comment: Why not use a transaction?

Comment: @reds 1 record per insert function where  table database is different from each other

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser iam still new, whats that :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to start transaction and rollback it when you catch the error.

Comment: how to do that, give an example ?

Comment: I canot get the thread link, but search for "try catch transaction rollback"